# Flex - RemoteObject - how to look at raw data received?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, fault, remoteobject

When using flex remote objects is there a way to look at the raw data received back from the server, for example as string?

I have a faultHandler set in my code and occasionally see faults, but the fault description in flex is very vague.  For example, it might show 'Delivery In Doubt', or similar.

I just want to know for sure whether I received any data from the server, and ideally, what it was.   Possibly if I had a server side error, I could see it in my client log in that case.

Note that these failures are not easy to reproduce, and I am familiar with sniffers such as fiddler.  The issue is end users will occasionally have a fault, which I keep track of, but I am hoping to get more information to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

> When using flex remote objects is there a way to look at the raw data
>   received back from the server, for example as string?

Yes, normally I would use ServiceCapture to do this.  Charles is another option; and Flash Builder even has some Network Monitor feature built right in to the IDE.  I see you mentioned Fiddler, which I believe to be in similar to the other tools.

I have never seen a fault handler give the message "delivery in doubt".  If you stop your code in debug mode; you can place a watch in your fault handler and look at the fault event.  From there you should be able to drill down into the actual error.  The [FaultEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/FaultEvent.html) should give you everything you need to know.

You can try taking a look at FaultEvent.[fault](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/FaultEvent.html#fault).[content](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/Fault.html#content) for the actual returned text.

Comment: My issue is that it rarely happens when I am debugging.  It might for example happen only a few times in a 24 hour period for the end users (20+ users).   So it's unlikely that I am going to be able to duplicate the issue to be able to sniff it or trace it using flex.

Comment: @ScottSzretter Perhaps it is [global error handling](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/global-exception-handling.html) you are looking for then?

Comment: Rarely happens; or never happens? If you can repliate it sometimesl; you're better off than most of us debugging user bugs.  There is no reason why you can't "capture" the content of the request; as I stated in my post and do something with it, such as displaying it to the user or capturing it in a log somehow; or sending it to a different service to email the results to you..

Comment: I think FaultEvent.fault.content might work for what I need, but it returns an object.   Whats the proper way to convert it to meaningful text?   I tried .toString() and String() around it and see "[object Object]".

Comment: [object Object] is the result of the default toString() method.  Since content is an Object; that is what I'd expect if you try to convert it to a String.  I suspect that will be more useful in debug mode; so you can try to figure out exactly what is getting returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
private function handleFault(e:FaultEvent):void
{
    trace(ObjectUtil.toString(e.fault.content));
}
```